# Resolution issue when building the game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using the ViewportHandler script for Unity(https://github.com/dfsp-spirit/way2close/blob/master/Way2Close/Assets/Scripts/ViewportHandler.cs), to allow for my UI to appear the same in different resolutions. I am pretty sure that it was looking just fine and pretty much the same in all resolutions(with different quality graphics due to stretching, but that is fine).

I have opened up my project after a while and I am now noticing that while the game scene looks fine inside the editor, the UI elements change position for all resolutions when building the game.

I am attaching two screenshots to show the difference. The Editor one is the proper one where elements are aligned properly. The other one is when I am building the game and running it full screen.

[image]
[image]

The weird thing is that when building the game, every resolution displays the wrong way (as in picture 1). So the elements are actually resizing properly, but they are just in the wrong place for some reason and I really can't see why. Any ideas ?

(My Canvas is Screen Space - Overlay, Scale with Screen Size, Ref resolution is 2560/1440, Match width and height and ref pixels 100).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 3rd party scripts to achieve a constant size on different resolutions. Use the Canvas Scaler component on your canvas and set it to 'Constant Physical Size'. Unity should handle all the rest.
[image]

If images/sprites change position, try to change the anchor point to fit your needs.

[image]

Comment: Hi! I don't really want to have constant size for my assets. It's ok if the images shrink or enlarge based on the resolution. The problem is that they don't stick to the proper position regardless of the resolution :(